# spray-json. How to get list of objects from json

Tags: json, scala, akka-http, spray-json

I am trying to use `akka-http-spray-json 10.0.9`

My model:

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String, age: Int)
```

I get json string `jsonStr` with list of persons and try to parse it:

```
implicit val personFormat: RootJsonFormat[Person] = jsonFormat3(Person)

val json = jsonStr.parseJson
val persons = json.convertTo[Seq[Person]]
```

Error:

> Object expected in field 'id'

Probably i need to create `implicit object extends RootJsonFormat[List[Person]]` and override `read` and `write` methods.

```
implicit object personsListFormat extends RootJsonFormat[List[Person]] {
    override def write(persons: List[Person]) = ???

    override def read(json: JsValue) = {
        // Maybe something like
        // json.map(_.convertTo[Person])
        // But there is no map or similar method :(
    }
}
```

**P.S.** Sorry for my english, it's not my native.

**UPD**
jsonStr:

```
[ {"id":6,"name":"Martin Ordersky","age":50}, {"id":8,"name":"Linus Torwalds","age":43}, {"id":9,"name":"James Gosling","age":45}, {"id":10,"name":"Bjarne Stroustrup","age":59} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get perfectly expected results with:

```
import spray.json._

object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val personFormat: JsonFormat[Person] = jsonFormat3(Person)
}

import MyJsonProtocol._

val jsonStr = """[{"id":1,"name":"john","age":40}]"""
val json = jsonStr.parseJson
val persons = json.convertTo[List[Person]]
persons.foreach(println)
```

Comment: I got `not found type CustomCollectionFormats`

Comment: Sorry for the edits and irrelevant comments..  my scala repl namespace was full of left overs..

Comment: yes it does. (using io.spray:spray-json_2.11:1.3.2)

Comment: It works great with hardcoded string(like in your answer), but fails with string, readed from file. Anyway thank you. I got the way to do it.